# como hacer bulk insert con hibernate y Java?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oracle-11g

Tengo un problema, necesito insertar miles de registros que se leen desde un file.properties, la idea es hacer bulk insert pero cuando ejecuto el batch me pide que el ID de la tabla no sea NULL, no entiendo porque lo pide, como puedo hacer que sea automático ?. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 11g no tiene una instrucción autoincrement como MySql o SQL Server, se debe de crear una secuencia y leer la secuencia para ir llenando los ID's

http://www.ajpdsoft.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=181

```
CREATE SEQUENCE nombre_secuencia
INCREMENT BY numero_incremento
START WITH numero_por_el_que_empezara
MAXVALUE valor_maximo | NOMAXVALUE 
MINVALUE valor_minimo | NOMINVALUE
CYCLE | NOCYCLE
ORDER | NOORDER
```

Y para usar la secuencia usas `nombre_secuencia.NextVal`

Comment: Hola, tuve que desechar esta idea ya que no podíamos depender de una secuencia para ello, a pesar de eso tu respuesta es la correcta. Gracias.